# convert nsstring 2013-04-18T06:53:26-04:00 to nsdate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to convert string `2013-04-18T06:53:26-04:00` to NSDate.
Here is my code.

```objc
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
assert(enUSPOSIXLocale != nil);

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
NSLog(@"str %@",[rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-04-18T06:53:26-04:00"]);
```

I am getting always (null)

Comment: I think you need to surround `T` in your date format with single quotes as it is literal letter T and not format string.

Comment: @Eimantas You should add that as an answer, that is the problem.

Comment: Try putting a few spaces in around T and the timezone

Comment: samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring...

Comment: check this link http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this

```
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```